# Copying global variable to local variable at time of function definition

Tags: r, global-variables

I am currently dealing with an issue in R, where I am trying to define functions in a `for` loop using the value of global values at the time the functions are defined. However every attempt seems to have some issue.

**Attempt 1:**
The first attempt was basic.

```
models = list()
nodes  = list(c(1), c(2))
d      = data.frame(CD=c(1,2))
for (i in 1:2) {
    models[[i]]         = list()
    models[[i]]$outcome = function(dat) {dat$CD %in% nodes[[i]]}

    cat(sprintf('\nIteration %d\n', i))

    cat(sprintf('\tModel %d outcome\n', i))
    print(models[[i]]$outcome(d))

    cat(sprintf('\tModel 1 outcome\n'))
    print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))
}
cat('\nFinal model 1 outcome')
print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))

cat('\nFinal model 2 outcome')
print(models[[2]]$outcome(d))
```

This gives the outcomes

```
Iteration 1
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE

Iteration 2
    Model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
    Model 1 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE

Final model 1 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE

Final model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

The function `models[[1]]$outcome` has been modified from the first iteration to the second as it depended on `nodes[[i]]` which has been changed, fair enough.

**Attempt 2:**
The second attempt was using a partial function in `pryr`.

```
library(pryr)
f = function(dat, x) {dat$CD %in% x}
models = list()
nodes  = list(c(1), c(2))
d      = data.frame(CD=c(1,2))
for (i in 1:2) {
    models[[i]]         = list()
    models[[i]]$outcome = partial(f, x=nodes[[i]])

    cat(sprintf('\nIteration %d\n', i))

    cat(sprintf('\tModel %d outcome\n', i))
    print(models[[i]]$outcome(d))

    cat(sprintf('\tModel 1 outcome\n'))
    print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))
}
cat('\nFinal model 1 outcome')
print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))

cat('\nFinal model 2 outcome')
print(models[[2]]$outcome(d))
```

This gives the same outcome

```
Iteration 1
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE

Iteration 2
    Model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
    Model 1 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE

Final model 1 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE

Final model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

This to me seems counter-intuitive. I would have expected a partial function to have copied the values of the inputs at the time the function was defined.

**Attempt 3:** I now attempted to use function closures.

```
f = function(x) { 
    g = function(dat) {dat$CD %in% x}
} 
models = list()
nodes  = list(c(1), c(2))
d      = data.frame(CD=c(1,2))
for (i in 1:2) {
    models[[i]]         = list()
    models[[i]]$outcome = f(nodes[[i]])

    cat(sprintf('\nIteration %d\n', i))

    cat(sprintf('\tModel %d outcome\n', i))
    print(models[[i]]$outcome(d))

    cat(sprintf('\tModel 1 outcome\n'))
    print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))
}
cat('\nFinal model 1 outcome')
print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))

cat('\nFinal model 2 outcome')
print(models[[2]]$outcome(d))
```

This gave the outcome

```
Iteration 1
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE

Iteration 2
    Model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
    Model 1 outcome
[1]  TRUE FALSE


Final model 1 outcome
[1] TRUE   FALSE

Final model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

It seems like we are finally getting somewhere. However there are two issues. Firstly something strange happens if we comment the print statements in the for loop.

```
f = function(x) { 
    g = function(dat) {dat$CD %in% x}
} 
models = list()
nodes  = list(c(1), c(2))
d      = data.frame(CD=c(1,2))
for (i in 1:2) {
    models[[i]]         = list()
    models[[i]]$outcome = f(nodes[[i]])

    #cat(sprintf('\nIteration %d\n', i))

    #cat(sprintf('\tModel %d outcome\n', i))
    #print(models[[i]]$outcome(d))

    #cat(sprintf('\tModel 1 outcome\n'))
    #print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))
}
cat('\nFinal model 1 outcome')
print(models[[1]]$outcome(d))

cat('\nFinal model 2 outcome')
print(models[[2]]$outcome(d))
```

We get the results

```
Final model 1 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE

Final model 2 outcome
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

So it seems the prints were causing us to copy the global variable at the time of the print statement (which is what I indirectly wanted). However, more annoyingly, I am running this inside a function and returning the `models` object. By doing this, the `models[[i]]$outcome` captures the whole environment it was defined in which means it ends up taking up (unnecessarily) a lot of memory.

**Question**

What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do i.e. copy the global variable at the time of the function definition as opposed to 'pointing' to it, without capturing the whole environment I have defined my function in.

Comment: Attempt 2: use `.lazy = FALSE`

Comment: I suggest googling around "R lazy evaluation" in general

Comment: Also you'll have a better idea of what's happening if you print `models[[1]]$outcome` rather than `models[[1]]$outcome(d)`

Comment: Attempt 3: "`force()`" `x`: `f <- function(x) {
  force(x) ;
  g = function(dat) dat$CD %in% x
} ` or simply `f <- function(x) {
  x ;
  g = function(dat) dat$CD %in% x
} `

Comment: In R, things usually work with less trouble when `apply`ing functions to `list`s rather than `for` loops with global variables: `models <- lapply(nodes, function(node) list(outcome = function(dat) dat$CD %in% node))`. This should solve your environment capturing problem at the same time. (`ls(pos = environment(models[[1]]$output))` consists only of `node`)